# How to go Another Activity from Android ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have Three Activity, such as; Android.Java, Windows.Java, Apple.Java, Blackberry.Java

When I click Android, Windows, Apple, Blackberry item on Listview, I Want to go these Activity.

**How can I go these Activity below code.**

Here my **Main_Activity.Java** Code

```html
package com.nasir.bd;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nasir.lv.EntryAdapter;
import com.nasir.lv.EntryItem;
import com.nasir.lv.Item;
import com.nasir.lv.SectionItem;
import com.sunil.sectionlist.R;

public class Main_Activity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
 
  ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
  ListView listview=null;
  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       
        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_main);
               
        items.add(new SectionItem("Mobile Version"));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.survey_g, "Android OS", "Lolipop", "android 5.1", "2014", "Google"));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.survey_g, "Windows OS", "Lumia", "Windows Phone 8.1", "2014", "Microsoft"));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.survey_g, "Apple iOS", "iPhone", "iOS 8", "2015", "Apple"));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.survey_g, "Blackberry", "Blackberry", "Blackberry 7.1", "2012", "Blackberry"));
        
        EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
  
  EntryItem item = (EntryItem)items.get(position);
  Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + item.Designation , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, Android.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be changed
depending on the position how the list elements are added:

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int    position, long arg3)  
    {

    EntryItem item = (EntryItem)items.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + item.Designation , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(position==1)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, Android.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(position==2)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, Apple.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    EntryItem item = (EntryItem)items.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + item.Designation , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(position = 0){
       Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, Android.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }else if(position = 1){
       Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, Windows.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }else if(position = 2){
       Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, Apple.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }else if(position = 3){
       Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, Blackberry.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Hope it works.!

Comment: Thanks for this answer
But I don't want to set Intent Command on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an if statement or something similar?

```
if(item.Designation.equals("Windows")
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, windows.class);
}
else if(item.Designation.equals("apple")
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, apple.class);
}
else if(item.Designation.equals("blackberry")
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, blackberry.class);
}
else if(item.Designation.equals("android")
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, android.class);
}

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks
This Code is Working Properly.